# Dynamic image gallery with thumbnails

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to create dynamic image gallery with thumbnails and popup full screen option.

Here is my HTML5 gallery (static version)

```
<div class="property__slider">
    <div class="property__ribon">Buy</div>

    <div id="properties-thumbs" class="slider slider--small js-slider-thumbs">
        <div class="slider__block js-slick-slider">
            <div class="slider__item slider__item--0"><a href="assets/media-demo/properties/big.jpg" data-size="1740x960" data-gallery-index='0' class="slider__img js-gallery-item"><img data-lazy="assets/media-demo/properties/big.jpg" src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span class="slider__description">1</span></a></div>
            <div class="slider__item slider__item--1"><a href="assets/media-demo/properties/big.jpg" data-size="1740x960" data-gallery-index='1' class="slider__img js-gallery-item"><img data-lazy="assets/media-demo/properties/big.jpg" src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span class="slider__description">2</span></a></div>
            <div class="slider__item slider__item--2"><a href="assets/media-demo/properties/big.jpg" data-size="1740x960" data-gallery-index='2' class="slider__img js-gallery-item"><img data-lazy="assets/media-demo/properties/big.jpg" src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span class="slider__description">3</span></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider slider--thumbs">
        <div class="slider__wrap">
            <div class="slider__block js-slick-slider">
                <div data-slide-rel='0' class="slider__item slider__item--0">
                    <div class="slider__img"><img data-lazy="assets/media-demo/properties/thumb.jpg" src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='1' class="slider__item slider__item--1">
                    <div class="slider__img"><img data-lazy="assets/media-demo/properties/thumb.jpg" src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='2' class="slider__item slider__item--2">
                    <div class="slider__img"><img data-lazy="assets/media-demo/properties/thumb.jpg" src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>

                <div data-slide-rel='3' class="slider__item slider__item--3">
                    <div class="slider__img"><img data-lazy="assets/media-demo/properties/thumb.jpg" src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <button type="button" class="slider__control slider__control--prev js-slick-prev">
                        <svg class="slider__control-icon">
                            <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-left"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="slider__control slider__control--next js-slick-next">
                        <svg class="slider__control-icon">
                            <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

*******UPDATED*******
And here is my php mysql version (dynamic) -

```
$id = $_GET['id']; 
             $name = $_GET['name']; 
             $my_images_arr = scandir('assets/media-demo/properties/'.$id);
             $directory = 'assets/media-demo/properties/'.$id.'/';  
             if ((glob($directory . '*.jpg') != false) || (glob($directory . '*.png') != false))
```

{
 $filecount = count(glob($directory . '*.jpg'))+count(glob($directory . '*.png'));

}

```
            $img_string = "";
            $cnt = 0;
            foreach($my_images_arr as $img_name)
            {
                $cnt = count($my_images_arr);
                $cnt = $cnt-2;

            if(strlen($img_name) >2)
                {

            $img_string .= '<img data-lazy="assets/media-demo/properties/'.$id.'/'.$img_name.'" src="assets/media-demo/properties/'.$id.'/'.$img_name.'">';
            //print_r($img_string);

                }


            }
 <div id="properties-thumbs" class="slider slider--small js-slider-thumbs">
                                  <div class="slider__block js-slick-slider">
                                  <?php for($i=1; $i<=$filecount; $i++) { ?>
                                    <div class="slider__item slider__item--<?php echo $i; ?>"><a href="assets/media-demo/properties/<?php echo $my_images_arr[2]; ?>" data-size="1740x960" data-gallery-index='<?php echo $i; ?>' class="slider__img js-gallery-item"><img data-lazy="assets/media-demo/properties/<?php echo $my_images_arr[2]; ?>" src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span class="slider__description"><?php echo $i; ?></span></a></div>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                  <div class="slider slider--thumbs">
                                  <div class="slider__wrap"> 
                                    <div class="slider__block js-slick-slider">
                                   <?php for($i=1; $i<=$filecount; $i++) { ?>
                                      <div data-slide-rel='<?php echo $i; ?>' class="slider__item slider__item--<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                        <div class="slider__img"><?php echo $img_string; ?></div>
                                      </div>
                                      <?php } ?>

                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="slider__control slider__control--prev js-slick-prev">
                                      <svg class="slider__control-icon">
                                        <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-left"></use>
                                      </svg>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="slider__control slider__control--next js-slick-next">
                                      <svg class="slider__control-icon">
                                        <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right"></use>
                                      </svg>
                                    </button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

I am facing problem  here

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<=$filecount; $i++) { ?>
                                          <div data-slide-rel='<?php echo $i; ?>' class="slider__item slider__item--<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                            <div class="slider__img"><?php echo $img_string; ?></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <?php } ?>
```

In thumbnails all three images are becoming a single image, loop has to be

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<=$filecount; $i++) { ?> <div class="slider__img"><?php echo $img_string; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

But if i did so,

```
<div data-slide-rel='<?php echo $i; ?>' class="slider__item slider__item--<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

this will be out of loop.

So not able to trace where i am doing wrong. Here is the screenshot how it looks now https://i.stack.imgur.com/65q8O.jpg

Comment: you can give a link to the screenshot image

Comment: Take a closer look at how each image is being displayed in the static version. It starts with `<div data-slide-rel='.. ` and not just the `<img>` element. Make sure your `$img_string` actually has all the code nessesary for each image.

Comment: @icecub: even after putting the same, its not coming. `slider__item slider__item--0` and `data-gallery-index='0'`, here also i should make it dynamic i guess.